# Find duplicate job names in BMC control-m

Tags: duplicates, jobs, control-m

I need to find duplicate job names in order to change them. How do I do that in BMC Control-M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your Control-M on Unix you could export your jobs with `ctmexdef` and then work with these files.

Export jobs:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for TABLE in `ctmpsm -SCHEDTAB -LISTTABLE "*" | sed '1d' | awk '{print $2}'`
do
   ctmexdef -TABLE $TABLE -ACTION DEFINE -FILE /tmp/${TABLE}.out
done
```

Print duplicate jobs:

```
grep ctmdefine /tmp/*.out | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a unix shell, you can use the control-m reporting facility to extract a set of job names, and maybe also table names. Export this as csv then sort in your favorite spreadsheet program (excel, open office, etc)